# When is normal bundle diffeomorphic to $M\times\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Using the definition of normal bundle from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863651/lees-proof-that-the-normal-bundle-is-embedded):

> Suppose $M\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ is an embedded $m$-dimensional
> submanifold. For each $x\in M$, we define the ***normal space to $\pmb
> > M$ at $\pmb x$*** to be the $(n-m)$-dimensional subspace
> $N_xM\subseteq T_x\Bbb R^n$ consisting of all vectors that are
> orthogonal to $T_xM$ with respect to the Euclidean dot product. The
> ***normal bundle of $\pmb{M}$***, denoted by $NM$, is the subset of $T\Bbb R^n\approx \Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ consisting of vectors that
> are normal to $M$: $NM = \big\{(x,v) \in \Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n : x\in M,\ v\in N_xM \big\}.$

Observing that $N_xM$ is a vector space of dimension $\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$, I would like to know if there are conditions when there exists a diffeomorphism from NM to $M\times\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$.

Comment: Do you want a bundle isomorphism between $NM$ and $M\times \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ or just a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Just a diffeomorphism. If a bundle isomorphism is also smooth, then that will do nicely, too.

Comment: Searching for such a bundle isomorphism is asking whether $NM$ is trivial, if you haven't seen that terminology. Now take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904386/condition-for-a-submanifold-to-have-a-trivial-normal-bundle

Comment: Could you clarify if that is a smooth bundle isomorphism?

Comment: Of course, the differential of a smooth function is smooth.